# Convert image of an irregular surface to it's signal equivalent

Tags: image-processing, signal-synthesis

I want to take the image of an irregular object , say

[image: unpolished road surface]

and then I want to convert the  elevation of the points into a spatial signal. To make my point clear: the signal would be 'height of the object's surface from an assumed datum' vs 'distance'.

For example

[image: elevation vs distance]

this is the kind of signal that I want to construct from my image.

What software/tool can I use to convert my image to it's signal equivalent?

Comment: Do you have any more information about the surface?  Multiple images from different angles?  Can you move the light to different angles?  Is the surface guaranteed to have the same color everywhere?

Comment: You must estimate depth first.

Comment: @endolith Suppose the images are taken at natural lighting condition (in a tropical country) in the early morning hours(as sunlight later can cast high contrast shadow of possible other surrounding objects). Multiple images will be taken at every 15 degree of full circle keeping an overlap of about 70%, say about 24 or more images will be taken.

I am a newbie in this field, I hope I have provided enough details.

Comment: You mean circling around a patch of land, or spinning the camera around in a panorama? You need to get the same land from multiple angles to figure out the depth

Comment: Yes, same land from multiple angles, exactly.

Comment: I doubt there exist a package -not even, for free!- for doing that quite sophisticated procedure..... And i think you will not be able to do that without a previous analysis of the problem, including the suggestion of all people here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from comments, you are taking multiple images from the same camera at diferent angle. So what you might be looking for is [Structure from motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion) .This is similar to Stereo vision. You can find open source solutions and software tools available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion#Structure_from_motion_software_toolboxes). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I have decided to use VisualSFM as of now, have you used any of these software tools yourself ?

Comment: No..I haven't used  these tools.